# Como usar o arquivo mvnw.cmd auto-gerado pelo site Spring Initializer?

Tags: maven

Como esse arquivo auto-gerado pode ser útil no dia a dia? Até tentei executar ele no MS-DOS mas não vi nada acontecer.

Comment: Esse `w` vem de _wrapper_/invólucro. Neste contexto, ele funciona como uma camada de abstração para o Maven embutido (o comando Maven tradicional é o `mvn`, o invólucro então `mvnw`)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.